# Why is the evolution-calendar-factory process running?

Tags: lightdm, ram, evolution

Why is the evolution-calendar-factory process running?

Here are some of the running processes (created with `ps aux --forest`)

```
lightdm
 \_ /usr/bin/X -core :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 \_ lightdm --session-child 12 31
     \_ init --user
         \_ ssh-agent
         \_ dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-tGrbQ6SZd8
         \_ /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
         \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
         \_ /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
```

AFAIK I don't need `evolution-calendar-factory`. I don't want it to run, since it takes up a lot of RAM 
Why is it started?

How to stop it starting the next time?

Comment: There's a bug report on this in Launchpad and there seems to be no workaround for Ubuntu 16.04 at the moment. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1589605

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use Evolution, you could just completely remove it, there are some instructions how to here:

[How do I completely remove Evolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315640/how-do-i-completely-remove-evolution)

Here is the command: `sudo apt-get --purge remove evolution evolution-exchange evolution-plugins evolution-common evolution-webcal`

Comment: only if you doesn't like of gnome... it will unistall gnome also