# I need to remove Evolution-Calendar and all of Evolution processes from Startup

Tags: gnome, evolution

I have seen this thread, but do not have the reputation(50) on this site yet to comment there:  [Remove evolution-calendar-factory from startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480753/remove-evolution-calendar-factory-from-startup)

When I try to use the hack to change the evolution folder names, it recreates them.  Processes that I kill get restarted.  This feels like completely malicious software/malware.  I will have to change from Gnome if this behavior continues.  Please help.