# dpkg-divert after disabling evolution

Tags: evolution

Since I don't use evolution, I decided to disable it by following these directions: https://askubuntu.com/a/694515/381089

The poster says that, "This should be done using dpkg divert and whatever, to not confuse apt/dpkg when you upgrade your system." I'm not too sure what he means by this. I tried the following command:
`sudo dpkg-divert --divert /dev/null /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook.service`
which seemed successful, but when I repeated the same command for `org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar` I got an error saying that it conflicts with the previous command.

Am I completely mistaken in how I'm using `dpkg-divert`?

Comment: Looking at [the examples in the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/dpkg-divert.1.html), `dpkg-divert --divert /dev/null /foo/bar` diverts `/dev/null`, not `/foo/bar`. You want the other way around.

Comment: I look at those examples quite a few times and I'm pretty sure I got the order correct. It says "To divert all copies of  a  `/usr/bin/example`  to  `/usr/bin/example.foo`,
       i.e.  directs  all packages providing `/usr/bin/example` to install it as
       `/usr/bin/example.foo`, performing the rename if required:

       `dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/example.foo --rename /usr/bin/example`. Notice the file being diverted is the last argument in the command.

Comment: Instead of diverting everything to /dev/null, I did the following: `sudo dpkg-divert --divert /tmp/org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook.service --rename /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook.service`, doing likewise for `Calendar.service`, `Sources.service`, and `UserPrompter.service`.