# How to make dpkg-divert remove instead of rename?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

A package I'm installing wants to add a config file to a shared `/.../config.d/` folder which another program reads on startup. I want to add my own configuration to replace the one installed by `apt`.

It's easy enough to "divert" the file with `dpkg-divert /.../config.d/package-config-file` but that just renames the file to `/.../config.d/package-config-file.distrib`. This happens because of a [documented behavior](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dpkg-divert):

> When adding, default is `--local` and `--divert <original>.distrib`.

This may be sufficient for some programs, but the program I'm using reads all files in `/.../config.d/` no matter the extension.

No matter because I can manually specify the `--divert` option:
`dpkg-divert --divert /dev/null /.../config.d/package-config-file`

This seems to work fine for one package. However when I want to do this for a second file, `dkpg-divert` doesn't like having two "diversions" going to the same file (`/dev/null`).

So, is there a good way to divert packages files you know you don't want to the trash?

I could make a `/trash` folder and put them all in there, but why keep that around.

Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever redirect to an important system file. Depending on your version of apt, this may or may not replace /dev/null with an ordinary file (so everything written to /dev/null will actually be written to disk). All redirections should be to regular files.